# Does the current Live USB made from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS have persistence?

Tags: live-usb, 18.04, lts, persistence

Just downloaded and installed the ISO of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS onto a flash drive. Does that have persistence? If not, how can I generate a Live USB with persistence?

Comment: LinuxLive USB Creator can do that, but that's a Windows-only program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Persistance is an option selected when a LiveUSB is generated, and a multi-OS tool to do that clearly is http://multibootusb.org/ .

Comment: excellent! the "multibootUsb TAB -> Install distro" worked great! I just had to gparted partition 1 as fat32 and partition 2 as ext4 (the way I wanted), prior to using multibootusb. Installed it on partition 1 and worked perfecly with a persistence we can setup up to 4GB (part1 had 15GB btw).

Comment: for now, v0.9.2 let me prepare the iso for 20.04 w/o persistence and w/o extracting iso contents, but it is ok, at least I can install the new OS version. I guess a future version will support 20.04 with persistence.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Etcher](https://etcher.io/). It's available for Linux, Mac and Windows. If you have windows I'll suggest [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).

Comment: Did not work :(. I tried balena etcher electron, the .deb package, I installed it on ubuntu 18.04. I tried to prepare a live USB with it's image, but the result is similar to the one we can have using "Startup Disk Creator" (despite the partitioning thru gparted is quite different). The point is, in the end, I had a iso9660 write protected blocking the whole 32GB of my pendrive, identical to what happened using SDC :(.